# Configure Centos 6.3 to direct all traffic through a proxy server

Tags: centos, proxy, http-proxy

Is there a way to configure CentOS 6.3 to direct all internet traffic through a proxy server?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of options here. One way to go would be to setup a [Squid proxy](http://www.squid-cache.org/) (software) that takes care of taking all the internet traffic and running it through itself. Once you have Squid setup on the box you can use something like [QuintoLabs Content Security](http://www.quintolabs.com/subscriptions.php) (commercial product but the community edition is free for personal use).

There is a thorough [tutorial here](http://www.howtoforge.com/web-filtering-on-squid-proxy) that you can follow.

The general steps are as follows:

- yum install squid
- yum install http://quintolabs.com/qlproxy/binaries/2.0.0/qlproxy-2.0.0-bb01d.i386.rpm
- configure quintolabs integration with squid
- startup squid and qlproxy (QuintoLabs daemon)
- install apache (QuintoLabs provides a web UI)